# Почему кнопки на телефоне расположены не правильно. А в юнити всё верно показывает

Tags: unity3d

У меня 3д проект в UNITY. Игра в самой UNITY работает нормально, но когда сбуилдил на телефон кнопки расположены не так как надо.[image: Это в юнити. Все кнопки на своих местах.]

[image: А это на телефоне]

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Скорее всего это происходит из-за смены разрешения, для этого нужно сделать адаптацию. Выбираешь каждый элемент и выбираешь в нем привязку к определённой стороне, к примеру джойстик к левому нижнему углу, а стрелочки к правому нижнему. После этого на любом разрешении всё должно отображатся корректно

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Можете подсказать пожалуйста как в зависимости от разрешения смартфона менялось и размер кнопок

Comment: Нужно перейти в настройки самого Canvas в котором находятся сами элементы и выбрать в UI Scale Mode параметр Scale With Screen Size. А Screen Match Mode же переключить на Match Width or Height если нужно чтобы менялись иконки в по мере изменения ширины и высоты